# How to use @property correctly (Setters) within another class

Tags: objective-c, properties, setter

another question i'm trying to use a setter within another class but I seem to get this odd error here is the code below:

## AppDataSorting.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface AppDataSorting : NSObject{
        NSString *createNewFood;
        NSNumber *createNewFoodCarbCount;
    }

    @property (readwrite) NSString *createNewFood;

    @end
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    - (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.foodName.stringValue);
        self.createNewFood = self.foodName.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"%.1f", self.carbAmount.floatValue);
    }
    @end
```

I get the error message in AppDelegate.m which is: Property 'createNewFood' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Could someone please explain the issue here?

Comment: Please see the answer shared by @Greg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare this property:

```
@property (readwrite) NSString *createNewFood;
```

In AppDataSorting.h so you can access it like self.createNewFood in AppDataSorting.m file not AppDelegate.m. If you want to call it as you do in AppDelegate.m you have move this line:

```
@property (readwrite) NSString *createNewFood;
```

to  AppDelegate.h file.

Or if you want to use property from AppDataSorting class in AppDelegate you have to create object and call it on that object:

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.foodName.stringValue);
        AppDataSorting *dSorting = [[AppDataSorting alloc] init];
        dSorting.createNewFood = self.foodName.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"%.1f", self.carbAmount.floatValue);
    }
```

Comment: You could access it in AppDataSorting if you want to put some logic or do other things with it, for example display description, this is why you declare it there. Can you update your question with the changes you made? It will work if you apply the above, I believe you make some mistake.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answer @Greg, curious though, why did i need to move the line to AppDelegate.h? also why did i not have to import AppDataSorting?

Comment: You don't have to move this line to AppDelegate, it's depends on what you need. If you move it to AppDelegate this property will be AppDelegate property not AppDataSorting property anymore. I don't know what your requirements are so I put a few option you should consider to make your app work. You have to import AppDataSorting in the file where you are going to use this class. If you don't use it in AppDelegate you don't have to import it. Sorry I cannot help if you don't explain what you trying to do and if you don't show some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In `-saveData:`, `self` refers to an instance of NSAppDelegate. The `createNewFood` property is defined on instances of the class `AppDataSorting`.

Also note that Cocoa/CF naming conventions give special meaning to methods that start with "init", "new" and (to a lesser degree) "create". You probably want to avoid such things in your property names. [Details here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE).

In general, properties should represent conceptual "properties" of an object. So if you had a `Person` class, it might have a `name` property, but it wouldn't have a `createNewOutfit` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `createNewFood` on an instance of `AppDataSorting` - but you're trying to access the property on the AppDelegate-class which clearly doesn't implement it.
So you would need to create an instance of AppDataSorting and then access the property like so:

```
AppDataSorting *instance = [[AppDataSorting alloc] init];
instance.createNewFood = self.foodName.stringValue;
```

Final notes:

- The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) provide a good base of information
- If you don't need atomicity you should always declare properties with the nonatomic attribute
- createNewFood is not a good name for a property since it suggests a method which creates new food - yet it's only meant to store data (in this case an NSString instance)